# Build silverlight application on tfspreview

Tags: silverlight, tfs, build-automation, azure-devops

I'm trying to setup an automated build on [tfspreview](http://tfspreview.com/) for a solution containing an SL5 project, but when I enqueue a new build I get an error from the agent, complaining that it can't find Microsoft.Silverlight.CSharp.targets. Normally I would install silverlight sdk/tools on the build server, but on tfspreview I don't have such privilege. Any idea to workaround the problem ?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to answer to my own question but after 5 months I think is acceptable. The problem has been solved by the TFS Team on an unspecified date. Now it's sufficient to specify X86 as the build Platform and it works.